# Is it possible to convert an object to std::optional without move or copy constructor?

Tags: c++, stdoptional

```
class A {
public:
    A() {
        std::cout << "constructor called\n";
    }

    ~A() {
        std::cout << "destructor called\n";
    }

private:
    A(const A&) = delete;
    void operator=(const A&) = delete;
};

A a() {
    return A();
}

std::optional<A> check(int condition) {
    if (condition) {
        return std::make_optional(a());
    }
    return std::nullopt;
}

int main() {
    auto event = check(true);

    std::cout << "main end\n";
}
```

This code doesn't compile with the copy constructor deleted. If I introduce the move constructor it works, but is it possible to do it without both copy and move constructors?

`check` can be like this which creates the object in place and it works

```
std::optional<A> check(int condition) {
    if (condition) {
        return std::make_optional<A>();
    }
    return std::nullopt;
}
```

But I need to go call another function which creates the object

Comment: Can we get an example of *But I need to go call another function which creates the object*?.   There should be a way to factor the code to both the things you needs.